# What does Python's builtin __build_class__ do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

In Python 3.1, there is a new builtin function I don't know in the `builtins` module:

```
__build_class__(...)
    __build_class__(func, name, *bases, metaclass=None, **kwds) -> class

    Internal helper function used by the class statement.
```

What does this function do? Why must it be in builtins if it's internal? What is the difference to the `type(name, bases, dict)` function?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Compiling the [PEP 3115](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) metaclass**

[Guido van Rossum said:](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-March/006338.html)

> The PEP proposes that the class
>   statement accepts keyword arguments,
>   `*args`, and `**kwds` syntax as well as positional bases. This is a bit messy
>   to compile and execute, but we already
>   have this, of course, in the code for
>   calling regular functions.
>
> So I think it would be acceptable to
>   this into a call to a new (hidden)
>   built-in function, named
>   `__build_class__`. Then that this class definition:
>
> ```
>   class C(A, B, metaclass=M, other=42, *more_bases, *more_kwds):
>     ...
> ```
>
> would translate into this:
>
> ```
>   C = __build_class__(<func>, 'C', A, B, metaclass=M, other=42,
> *more_bases, *more_kwds)
> ```
>
> where `<func>` is a function object for
>   the class body.

Comment: What is the "function object for the class body"?

Comment: You can find this information in the code example in the linked post from Guido van Rossum.

`__build_class__` will call something like `locals = {}; func(locals)`.

That is, for a class `class X: y = 1`, the equivalent body function `<func>` would be: `def func(locals): locals.y = 1`