# Python Why am I getting not defined error?

Tags: python

when I use any class variable in class code blocks, I'm getting not defined error. how can I fix it ?

example

```
class A():
    __hidden_number__ = 5
    __no_hidden_number__ = A.__hidden_number__ + 4 # to cause error. why ?
```

Thanks.

Comment: try `__no_hidden_number__ = __hidden_number__ + 4`

Comment: Because `A` is not defined yet.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga nope. You're in `A` scope. You're refering to `A.A`. Check my answer and test the snippet.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This sounds misleading. `A` has an outer scope. If there's an `A` already in the enclosing namespace, `A.__hidden_number__` would refer to that. Inside the class declaration the *name* of the class you are currently declaring is not part of the resolution hierarchy.

Comment: @dhke: you're saying that I'm not using the correct vocabulary? possible. Can you help on that?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm not sure, but I'd rather be precise. When you're inside the class decl, you are building a code object for the class. (`dis.disassemble()` is very helpful, here). That code object gets assigned to the name `A` in the enclosing namespace. Which is why you don't have `A` inside the class declaration, because that name hasn't gotten assigned at that point, yet.

Comment: @dhke I'll look into this disassemble thing. But have you checked my 2 code snippets? I think they speak for themselves.

Comment: I've tried to disassemble class construction, but could not. Not sure it can be done (as you see I hate when someone doesn't agree with me :), I mean I don't like when we don't understand each other arguments or even _facts_.))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, but *while the class definition is being executed* the `A` namespace doesn't exist. Or, at least, it *isn't assigned to the name `A`*. This is why you need to use string-literals to provide ["forward references"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references), and why the error is a `NameError`. Someone with better knowledge of the Python data model could say better whether the namespace doesn't exist or isn't assigned to the name. To disassemble the class creation, though, try something like `dis.dis(compile("class A: pass",'test', 'exec'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your class variable is already in `A` namespace.

So you just have to do:

```
__no_hidden_number__ = __hidden_number__ + 4
```

else you're trying to access `A.A` and it doesn't exist yet.

To illustrate what I'm stating, that "works" (but not what you want):

```
class A():
    class A():
        __hidden_number__ = 4
    __no_hidden_number__ = A.__hidden_number__ + 4
A()  # that works
```

that doesn't:

```
class A():
    class B():
        __hidden_number__ = 4
    __no_hidden_number__ = A.__hidden_number__ + 4  # B.__... would've worked
A()  # beeep: NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

note that you should avoid to define private attributes with trailing double underscore (`__xxx__`). It works, but this is generally reserved for python special class members (`__class__`, `__file__`, `__eq__`, etc...). Name mangling (making the object "private") already occurs with 2 leading underscores.

Comment: Note that the question is *Why* the error appears. Well, `A` isn't defined before the class declaration is finished.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Erm? Yes? The name `A` is assigned strictly after the class declaration.

Comment: try my snippet, and then change the inner `A` by `B` and see what happens

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry about that. Didn't mean to stop on your edit.

Comment: @ChristianDean no sweat. Didn't rollback, just added the line that was deleted. thanks for editing (yet :)).

Answer (score 2):

Since this might be a little unclear (the existing answer is fine), let me add to that:

```
class A:
    pass
```

[is equivalent to](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)

```
A = type('A', (object,), {})
```

What we write inside the class declaration is essentially building that (here empty) dictionary and that happens *before* the variable `A` gets assigned. And since we have --not yet-- a variable of the name `A` in the namespace hierarchy while the class declaration runs, `A` isn't available.

The class exists, it also has the *type name* `'A'`, but it hasn't gotten  assigned to the variable `A`, yet.

The difference between the `class A: pass`-version and the explicit `type` call is syntactic sugar: When using `class`, everything nested inside the class is automatically namespaced into the class dictionary.

This is why this works:

```
class A:
   var = 1
   var2 = var + 1
```

But as we can see above, the local variable `A` that will finally hold our new class is assigned only after the class declaration has already been evaluated and thus isn't available inside of it.

If we disassemble a class decl, we get:

```
  import codeop, dis
  dis.disassemble(codeop.compile_command('class A:\r\n    pass'))

1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('A')
            3 LOAD_CONST               3 (())
            6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object A at 0x80076ff30, file "<input>", line 1>)
            9 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
           12 CALL_FUNCTION            0
           15 BUILD_CLASS         
           16 STORE_NAME               0 (A)
           19 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
           22 RETURN_VALUE
```

`19` and `22` are added automatically, since code objects must return a value. We can ignore those for our example.

What else is happening here?

- `0`: pushes the string `'A'` onto the stack. This will become the name of the class (the first argument to `type()`).
- `3`: pushes an empty tuple, the list of parent classes
- `6`: Loads the code object for the class declaration.
- `9` and `12` run the class declaration code object. This is what e.g. does our (class) variable assignments. It returns the class dictionary.
- `15` builds the class onto the stack. This is equivalent to `type('A', (), class_dict)`, where the parameters are exactly the values on the stack at this point.

And finally:

- `16` stores the freshly created class into the local namespace under the name `A`.

As we can see, the class declaration is run (`12`), before the class is assigned to its variable `A` (`16`).

Note that the disassembly is different in Python 3, because python as a special builtin [class builder function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832997/what-does-pythons-builtin-build-class-do).

And yes, this is far too long an answer ;-).

Comment: now I get it. This just _cannot_ be the same `A` since it's being constructed. So we're both right. your answer is a nice add-on that I had overlooked.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I was not trying to say you were wrong, but the details are a little nasty. Python is a stack machine and distinguishing between "the type object `'A'` on the stack" and a "variable with the name `A` to hold that type object" makes the difference here.