# Python base class can be object without __mro_entries__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today I have discovered that python object without `__mro_entries__` can be used as a base class.

Example:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}(*{self.args!r})'


class Delivered(Base):
    pass


b = Base()
d = Delivered()


class Foo(b, d):
    pass


print(type(Foo) is Delivered)
print(Foo)
```

```py
True
Delivered(*('Foo', (Base(*()), Delivered(*())), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Foo'}))
```

As a result `Foo` will be instance of a `Delivered` class and it's not a valid type.

I do understand use case of `__mro_entries__` but what use case of using object without `__mro_entries__` as a base class. Is it a bug at python?

Comment: `Foo` is not just an instance of `Delivered`. It's an instance of `d`, which is an instance of `Delivered`. This is neat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR Not a bug, but an extreme abuse of the `class` statement.

---

A `class` statement is [equivalent to a call to a metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832997/what-does-pythons-builtin-build-class-do). Lacking an explicit `metaclass` keyword argument, the metaclass has to be inferred from the base class(es). Here, the "metaclass" of the "class" `b` is `Base`, while the metaclass of `d` is `Delivered`. Since each is a non-strict subclass of a common metaclass (`Base`), `Delivered` is chosen as the more specific metaclass.

```
>>> Delivered('Foo', (b, d), {})
Delivered(*('Foo', (Base(*()), Delivered(*())), {}))
```

`Delivered` can be used as a metaclass because it accepts the same arguments that the `class` statement expects a metaclass to accept: a string for the name of the type, a sequence of parent classes, and a mapping to use as the namespace. In this case, `Delivered` doesn't use them to create a type; it simply prints the arguments.

As a result, `Foo` is bound to an instance of `Delivered`, not a type. So `Foo` is a class only in the sense that it was produced by a `class` statement: it is decidedly *not* a type.

```
>>> issubclass(Foo, Delivered)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
>>> Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Delivered' object is not callable
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. When we create class it actually call `__build_class__` function to create class and it's behave differently if compare to `type` call. So I think it should not be the same as `type` result because any callable object can be used as a metaclass not only `type` and delivered from `type` classes.

Comment: Right; I will update the answer in moment to address that more directly, rather than meandering into the explanation the way it currently does.  (I forgot about metaclass inference when I wrote the original answer.)

Comment: I was actually unaware of the existence of `__build_class__` as the connection between a `class` statement and a call to a metaclass. I've added a link to a another question that explains it, rather than duplicating that part here.